# How do I put a TreeView in a DevExpress ComboBox?

Tags: combobox, treeview, devexpress

How do I place a TreeView in the drop-down of a ComboBox?

Answer (score 1):

You should use PopupContainerEdit control from DevExpress XtraEditors Library.

See the documentation [Here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPopupContainerEdittopic). It can be done with 5 line of code. End result is amazingly good and it's free.

Comment: That's what my sample below does.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add any extra libraries, it is possible to do this with the [`DropDownEdit`](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxDropDownEdit/CheckComboBox.aspx) control to emulate a ComboBox.  Just add your TreeView to the `DropDownWindowTemplate` and set `AllowSelectNode=true`.